# Where do I find properties for scripting an Enterprise Application from an application template

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, azure-databricks

I'm attempting to automate deployment of an Azure Active Directory (AAD) Enterprise Application from an application template, specifically the Azure Databricks SCIM Provisioning Connector template. I can successfully create an application using the Azure Portal but I need to automate this using PowerShell or Microsoft Graph.

I found that using a REST client I can POST the following JSON body to change the name of the Enterprise Application. However, I'm coming up short on how to set the following: provisioning mode and scope, tenant url, and how to assign users and groups to the EA.

```
{
  "displayName": "Created using Microsoft Graph"
}
```

Any ideas where I can find this information? I looked at the JSON response from https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applicationTemplates and it doesn't list any such properties. Unfortunately, I don't recall where I found the sample payload to change the displayName property but I don't remember that webpage showing other properties anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will get you closer: After you have created the Application from an Application template, you can update the properties as documented in [Microsoft Graph: Update Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/{id}

{
    "displayName": "My Cool App",
    "identifierUris": [
        "https://MyApp.com"
    ],
    "appRoles": [
        {
             "allowedMemberTypes": [
             "User"
        ],
        "description": "NormalUser",
        "displayName": "NormalUser",
        "id": "1e2e460f-6565-47c0-9596-bd461e70477c",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "origin": "Application",
        "value": "NormalUser"
    },
    "web": {
        "redirectUris": [
            "https://MyApp.com/login"
        ],
         "homePageUrl": "https://MyApp.com",
            "logoutUrl": null,
            "implicitGrantSettings": {
                "enableIdTokenIssuance": true,
                "enableAccessTokenIssuance": false
            }
    },
}
```

To test Microsoft Graph features out and explore, I highly recommend visiting their [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). To get the settings correct, fully configure an application, GET the settings, and use the JSON to PATCH your updates to the Application.